# Scilab: Invalid Index

Tags: loops, matrix, scilab

I try to calculate a mean value of 10 matrix entries (1:10, 2:11, 3:12 and so on) and then make a new matrix out of these mean values. However, it always gives me Invalid Index.

```
A=rand(150,1);
number_of_rows=size(A,1);
for i=1:number_of_rows
  B=mean(A(i:i+9,1),1);
  C(i,:)=B;
end
```

Comment: Solved!
The problem with the last entries of the matrix, cause (i+9) at the last 9 entries was not valid anymore.
Therefore, I just edited the third row:

    for i=1:(number_of_rows-9)

Comment: a more efficient and straight forward way is to use the conv function

Comment: C=conv(A,ones(10,1),"valid")

Answer (score 1):

The trivial following code does it, for any window's length n:

```
A = grand(1,40,"uin",0,9)
n = 10;

C = [0 cumsum(A)];
C = (C(n+1:$)-C(1:$-n))/n
```

Result (sample):

```
-->     A = grand(1,40,"uin",0,9)
 A  = 
         column 1 to 24
   3.   2.   2.   9.   2.   6.   1.   5.   1.   5.   7.   2.   5.   8.   3.   0.   3.   8.   3.   3.   4.   8.   8.   1.

         column 25 to 40
   4.   2.   0.   8.   5.   8.   5.   3.   7.   3.   1.   8.   8.   0.   0.   4.

-->     n = 10;
-->     C = [0 cumsum(A)];
-->     C = (C(n+1:$)-C(1:$-n))/n
 C  = 
         column 1 to 20
   3.6   4.   4.   4.3   4.2   4.3   3.7   3.9   4.2   4.4   4.2   3.9   4.5   4.8   4.1   4.2   4.4   4.1   4.1   4.3

         column 21 to 31
   4.8   4.9   4.4   4.3   4.5   4.2   4.8   5.6   4.8   4.3   3.9

--> mean(A(1:n))
 ans  =
   3.6
```

However, cumsum() would propagate any Inf or NaN value belonging to A.